# How to find tables all relation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to find tables all relation in MySQL. whether it references some table, or some other table will take its reference.

For example, suppose `student` is a table which contains `id (primary key)`, `name`, `class(Foreign key refers class table id field)` element. And class is an another table which contains `id(primary key)`, `name`. and another table student_account is an another table which contains `id(primary key)`, `student_id(Foreign key refers student table id field)`,`due`.

Now how may I find all relation of table `student`.

Comment: Thanks looks like a bit helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
 FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = Your_Table_Name
 AND REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA IS NOT NULL AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL AND
 REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: "Your_table_name" should read "Your_schema_name" in the restriction for this to work.